# Updating partial view from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, partial-views

I have read some tutorials on how to update a partial view but they all assume a user interaction as a starting point (like a dropdown change that will cause the updating of a some data in a partial view). My situation is different: I am trying to update the partial view starting from the controller, without user interaction on the UI. If I use such code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PerformAction(MyModel mymodel)
    {
        //....do things

        return PartialView("Notification", mymodel);
    }
```

The browser will display ONLY the partial view. Suggestions ? Thanks

Here is the main view:

```
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@model MyApplication.Models.Mymodel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<form class="float_left" method="post" action="@Url.Action("Start", "Home")">
    <fieldset>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new { Value = Model.Message })
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe"/>
        <div id="notificationMessage">
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/PartialView.cshtml", new PartialViewModel()); }
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and here the partial:

```
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@model HostedExchangeListener.Models.PartialViewModel
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Message, new { Value = Model.Message })
```

Comment: Because you are returning a `PartialView` by the sounds of things it seems like you want to use AJAX to render the partial view? So it does not reload the page

Comment: In the tutorials I saw Ajax is used but it assumes some user interaction on the page.

Comment: Well there are a few ways, you can use ajax when the DOM loads to load in the Partial View, or you can just pass in a model to the partial. Can you post your View that you want to render the partial on and also your partial.

Comment: When I first load the page the partial view is empty, and that's ok. But then I would like it to be updated in according to some logic that resides on the controller. The views are very simple (I'll update the post to show them)

Comment: When do you want to update it? Straight away? Or when something changes?

Comment: not straight away, updates happens regularly but delayed in time (after the page is loaded).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is something along these lines:

**View**

```
<div id="partialViewContent"> </div>

<script>
$(function () // Once the DOM is loaded
{
    setInterval(function(){ 
        $.get('@Url.Action("Action","Controller")', function(data) {
        $('#partialViewContent').html(data); // Replace whats in the div with the PartialView
    }, 5000); // Every 5 seconds
});

</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Action()
{
    var mymodel = new MyViewModel();
    //....do things
    return PartialView("Notification", mymodel);
}
```

Comment: This solution does not really fullfill my needs. If I understand right It will call my action every 5 seconds, so it is the ui that decides to ask for an update. My question is if the controller can decide to update the partial view. (My controller listens to external services and needs to update the partial view when he receives messages)

Comment: You are going to need something like SignalR to update the view. Really this information should have been in your question. To push out updates from the controller to the view you will probably need a bit of rework to your current implementation.